# How to install imsart?

Tags: installing

I would like to use imsart package downloaded from
http://www.e-publications.org/ims/support/ims-instructions.html .

I unzipped it and copied on `C:\usr\local\share\texmf\tex\latex\imsart-ims`
Then I used command mktexlsr , and compiled

```
\documentclass[aop]{imsart}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

as a test, but the following error message appeared.

> This is pTeX, Version 3.141592-p3.1.4 (sjis) (Web2C 7.5.3)
>   (format=platex 2004.10.11)  23 NOV 2015 17:40
>   **test (./test.tex pLaTeX2e <2004/08/10>+0 (based on LaTeX2e <2003/12/01> patch level 0)
>   (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/imsart-ims/imsart.cls Document
>   Class: imsart 2010/04/27 driver class for package imsart.sty
>   (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls Document Class:
>   article 2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX document class
>   (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo File: leqno.clo
>   1998/08/17 v1.1c Standard LaTeX option (left equation numbers) )
>   (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/size11.clo File: size11.clo
>   2004/02/16 v1.4f Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) \c@part=\count81
>   \c@section=\count82 \c@subsection=\count83 \c@subsubsection=\count84
>   \c@paragraph=\count85 \c@subparagraph=\count86 \c@figure=\count87
>   \c@table=\count88 \abovecaptionskip=\skip41 \belowcaptionskip=\skip42
>   \bibindent=\dimen118 )
>   (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/imsart-ims/imsart.sty File:
>   imsart.sty 2014/10/16IMS article style (VS)
>
> No file imsart.cnf. (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/base/leqno.clo
>   File: leqno.clo 1998/08/17 v1.1c Standard LaTeX option (left equation
>   numbers) ) \c@firstpage=\count89 \c@lastpage=\count90
>   \c@thanks=\count91 \c@addressref=\count92
>
> (c:/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty Package:
>   keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC) \KV@toks@=\toks15 )
>   \c@emailref=\count93
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.831 \protected
>                   \def\relateddoi{\@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@relateddoi}{\@t... The
>   control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was
>   never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and
>   the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and
>   I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. l.834 \protected
>                   \def\relateddois{\@ifnextchar[{\@tempswatrue\@relateddois}{... The
>   control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was
>   never \def'ed. If you have misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type`I' and
>   the correct spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue, and
>   I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
>
> \c@author=\count94 \c@address=\count95 \sv@mathsurround=\dimen119
>   \sv@parindent=\dimen120 \fm@box=\box41 \fm@size=\dimen121
>   \t@xtheight=\dimen122 \abstract@box=\box42 \keyword@box=\box43
>   \pre@kwd@depth=\dimen123 \keyword@toks=\toks16 \authors@list=\toks17
>   \keywords@list=\toks18 No file imsart-aop.cnf. )) (./test.aux)
>   \openout1 = `test.aux'.
>
> LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line
>   2. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:
>   ... okay on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for
>   OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input
>   line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on
>   input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2. LaTeX Font
>   Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 2. LaTeX
>   Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking
>   defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay
>   on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for JY1/mc/m/n
>   on input line 2. LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2. LaTeX
>   Font Info:    Checking defaults for JT1/mc/m/n on input line 2. LaTeX
>   Font Info:    ... okay on input line 2.  (./test.aux) )  Here is how
>   much of TeX's memory you used:  913 strings out of 95555  10899 string
>   characters out of 1191355  58914 words of memory out of 1500000  4122
>   multiletter control sequences out of 10000+50000  8274 words of font
>   info for 34 fonts, out of 600000 for 2000  14 hyphenation exceptions
>   out of 2000  30i,1n,21p,301b,40s stack positions out of
>   1500i,500n,5000p,200000b,5000s
>
> No pages of output.

What should I do to cancel this message?

Comment: It seems that you're using pTeX with a version that doesn't accept e-TeX extensions. Update your TeX system.

Answer (score 1):

The missing `.cnf` files are not a problem; the important issue is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.831 \protected
```

which means you have a too old version of pTeX that doesn't sport e-TeX extensions like the more recent releases. I can only go back to TeX Live 2012 (`pTeX 3.1415926-p3.3) and with it the test document runs smoothly

Upgrade your TeX distribution.